# Error while opening generated excel file in php codeigniter using phpExcel

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

This how look generated excel file  :
with the warning messages :
Message:  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?
Filename: Shared/OLE.php

This is comes in excel file -
þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ @€Åfôí*Ö@€Åfôí*ÖþÿÕÍÕœ.“—+,ù®0¼HPX`hp

I have tried with iconv(mb_detect_encoding($result, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $result); coversion as well.

This is the code :

```
 public function exportExcel() {
    $this->load->library('excel');
    $registrationIDArr = $_POST["registrationID"];
    $resigtrationIDStr = implode(",",$registrationIDArr);
    $currDate = date("d-m-Y_H_i");
    $file = 'VolunteerRegistration_'.$currDate.'.xls';
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Volunteer Details');
    $style = array('font' => array('size' => 12,'bold' => true));

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:B1')->applyFromArray($style);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Name');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'Email');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(25);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(25);

    $rows = 2;

    $result = $this->getVolunteerDetailsForExcelExport($resigtrationIDStr);

    foreach($result as $row){ 
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$rows, $row->name);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rows, $row->email);
      $rows++;  

    }


    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');



    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');


   ob_end_clean();
   ob_start();
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
     exit;
}

public function getVolunteerDetailsForExcelExport($registrationIDStr){

    $this->db->select("CONCAT(fname,' ',mname,' ',lname) AS name, email");
    $this->db->from('UserRegistration');
    $wherelist = "id in($registrationIDStr)";
    $this->db->where($wherelist);
    $query= $this->db->get();

    $result = $query->result();

    return $result;

}
```

Comment: The last version of [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) was released in 2015 and it is now marked as dead. You are instead encouraged to used the replacement, [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet), which I would also strongly recommend. In PHP 7.3, a special warning was added to `switch` statements which is what you are seeing. There are not plans by the author to fix this, so your only alternative would be to fork the code and fix things on your own.

Comment: Also, the message about `continue` is a warning, not an error. Is there something else breaking? If so, please describe.

Comment: @thelr excel file comes with Unicode characters

Comment: Got it. is there an error printed when PHP gets to the unicode? Usually it would be prefixed by "Fatal Error".

Comment: I solved issue by using PhpSpreadsheet and there also I face Unicode problem so this two lines of code before and after write solved unicode problem: ob_end_clean();
$writer->save('php://output');
exit();

Answer (score 1):

In PHPExcel/Shared/OLE.php,`function _readPpsWks($blockId)`, there is an error in the for / switch structure.
In the default case of the switch, you write `continue;`. But this does NOT exit the `for` loop. It only exits the "switch" structure, and continue under. You have to write: `continue 2;`, at line number 290.

```
default:
    continue 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it might helps. This works for me.

```
require 'PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
/*CODE for excel*/
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="file.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```